# C++ does not want a return value

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, return

I'm trying some exercise to learn the use of pointers with arrays and functions.
So I tried to code a "strange way" to find out primes within a certain range.

The problem is that the output always add the return value of the function with the algorithm for the primes. if I omit it, it shows is '32767', if I write `return *pt`, it adds the last number of the range, even if it's not a prime!

Just tried it with number 6: it's not a prime but it pops up!

```
#include <iostream>
int show_primes(const int * begin, const int * end);
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int i = 0;
    int End_Array = 0;
    cout << "Write the last number in your range (it always start from number 2)";
    cin >> End_Array;
    i=End_Array;
    int cookies[i];
    for(i=-1; i<End_Array; i++)
       cookies[i] = i+1;
    cout << show_primes(cookies, cookies + End_Array-1);
}
int show_primes (const int * begin, const int * end)
{
    using namespace std;
    const int * pt;
    int z = 0;
    for (pt = begin; pt < end; pt++, z=0)
    {
        for (int n=2; n<=*pt; n++)
        if ( *pt%n == 0 )
            ++z;
        if (z==1)
            cout << *pt <<endl;
    }
    return *pt ;
}
```

Comment: Why does this function need a return value at all?

Comment: At the very least, writing to `cookies[-1]` causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Actually I'm not so sure... but if you don't put a return value, what happens is that it adds '32767' and I don't know where it comes from!!

Comment: I believe `int cookies[i];` is also illegal in `C++`. Might work in the latest `C` I think.

Comment: Since `show_primes()` prints the primes it finds, it probably shouldn't return a value (should return `void`) and should not be used in a print statement.  It returns 6 because when the loop finishes, `pt` points at the end value, which is 6 when that's what you type. If you don't explicitly return a value, you get semi-random garbage returned. You're probably using G++ because you're using a VLA (variable length array) which is a C99 feature not in C++11 except with G++ (and perhaps `clang` too for GCC compatibility).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for(i=0; i<End_Array; i++) // Start from zero
    cookies[i] = i; //Use i

 // Don't use cout
 show_primes(cookies, cookies + End_Array-1);
```

Comment: It's not the address that's printed.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is accessing a value at negative index.

```
 cookies[i] = i+1;   //For first iteration, value of i is -1
```

So `for(i=-1; i<End_Array; i++)` should be changed to `for(i=0; i<End_Array; i++)`

Also, you do not need to return from the function as you are printing the values within itself

Although you are using pointers for your learning, a more simpler implementation would be:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void show_primes(int num)
{
    bool flag = false;
    for (int pt = 2; pt < num; pt++)
    {
        if ( num%pt == 0 )
        {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!flag)
    {
        cout<<num<<' ';
    }
}
int main()
{
    int End_Array = 0;
    cout << "Write the last number in your range(>2)";
    cin >> End_Array;
    for(int i=2; i<End_Array; i++)
    {
        show_primes(i);
    }
}
```

**P.S.:** Can someone please highlight that is it a bad practice to include `std` namespace in every functional block as OP has done.(I think it is)

Comment: Ok Thanks... I chenged it to not-negative, but nothing of different happens!